Bromwich integral in evaluation of Green function of 1+1D Klein-Gordon equation
When I'm evaluating Green function of 1+1D Klein-Gordon equation using integral transform techniques, I have done in many ways of taking integral transform, I have got

\begin{equation}
    G(x,x',t,t')= \frac{c}{2} J_0 \left(\mu \sqrt{(t-t')^2-\frac{|x-x'|^2}{c^2}}\right) \Theta\left(t-t'-\frac{|x-x'|}{c}\right).
\end{equation}

In one way, I'm stucked. Let describe, the impulsive equation for 1+1D Klein-Gordon equation is,

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 G(x,x',t,t')}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 G(x,x',t,t')}{\partial x^2} + {\mu}^2 G(x,x',t,t')= \delta(x-x')\delta(t-t').
\end{equation}

After taking Laplace and Fourier transform,

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\overline{G}}(k,x',s,t')=\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{ikx'-st'}}{s^2+k^2c^2+\mu^2}.
\end{equation}

Now taking inverse Fourier transform,

\begin{equation}
    \overline{G}(x,x',s,t')=\frac{c}{2} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{s^2+\mu^2}\frac{|x-x'|}{c}}}{\sqrt{s^2+\mu^2}} e^{-st'}.
\end{equation}

Taking inverse Laplace transform, the Bromwich integrals becomes

\begin{equation}
    G(x,x',t,t')=\frac{c}{4\pi i} \Theta(t-t') \int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{s^2+\mu^2}\frac{|x-x'|}{c}}}{\sqrt{s^2+\mu^2}} e^{s(t-t')}ds.
\end{equation}

The square root is computed by taking the branch cuts to run from $s = ai$ out to $+∞i$ and from $s = −ai$ out to $−∞i$; the cuts are along the imaginary axis. How Bromwich contour will be made and path of integration with their limits?
